# Query very slow and not using index - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm using facets to reduce index memory allocation.

Here is an example of one of the documents (over a million docs in the collection):

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5461c8f1426f727f169d0000"),
    "n": "X-Men: Days of Future Past",
    "f": [
            {
                "t": "ry",
                "v": 2014
            }, 
            {
                "t": "g",
                "v": [
                    "Action",
                    "Adventure",
                    "Sci-Fi"
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "t": "ml",
                "v": "English"
            },
            {
                "t": "k",
                "v": "movie"
            },
            {
                "t": "rel",
                "v": true
            }
        ],
    ai: 1898267,
    ec: 3
}
```

There are more fields, but not relevant for the case.

The "f" field describe the facets. And these are the indexes I created for the queries I have to make:

```
{
    "f.t" : 1,
    "f.v" : 1,
    "ai" : -1
}
```

And:

```
{ ec: -1 }
```

Now, the query I'm trying to execute is this:

```
db.items.find({"$and": [
        {"f": {"$elemMatch": {t: "ml", v: {"$in": ["English", "Spanish", "French", "German"]}}}}, 
        {"f": {"$elemMatch": {t: "rel", v: true}}}, 
        {"f": {"$elemMatch": {t: "k", v: "movie"}}}, 
        {"f": {"$elemMatch": {t: "ry", v: 2014}}}, 
        {"f": {"$elemMatch": {t: "g", v: {"$in": ["Action"]}}}}
]
}).limit(12)
```

It takes forever. I'm afraid that maybe there are some problems at server level with memory allocation.

Here is the explain() document:

```
{
    "cursor": "BtreeCursor f.t_1_f.v_1_ai_-1",
    "isMultiKey": true,
    "n": 12,
    "nscannedObjects": 228327,
    "nscanned": 228327,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 228327,
    "nscannedAllPlans": 228327,
    "scanAndOrder": false,
    "indexOnly": false,
    "nYields": 87096,
    "nChunkSkips": 0,
    "millis": 120605,
    "indexBounds": {
    "f.t": [
        [
            "rel",
            "rel"
        ]
    ],
    "f.v": [
        [
            true,
            true
        ]
    ],
    "ai": [
        [{
            "$maxElement": 1
        }, {
            "$minElement": 1
        }]
    ]
    },
    "server": "h00222.mongolab.com:42100",
    "filterSet": false,
    "stats": {
    "type": "LIMIT",
    "works": 315226,
    "yields": 87096,
    "unyields": 87096,
    "invalidates": 0,
    "advanced": 12,
    "needTime": 228315,
    "needFetch": 86899,
    "isEOF": 1,
    "children": [{
        "type": "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
        "works": 315226,
        "yields": 87096,
        "unyields": 87096,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "advanced": 12,
        "needTime": 228315,
        "needFetch": 86899,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "children": [{
            "type": "FETCH",
            "works": 315226,
            "yields": 87096,
            "unyields": 87096,
            "invalidates": 0,
            "advanced": 12,
            "needTime": 228315,
            "needFetch": 86899,
            "isEOF": 0,
            "alreadyHasObj": 0,
            "forcedFetches": 0,
            "matchTested": 12,
            "children": [{
                "type": "IXSCAN",
                "works": 228327,
                "yields": 87096,
                "unyields": 87096,
                "invalidates": 0,
                "advanced": 228327,
                "needTime": 0,
                "needFetch": 0,
                "isEOF": 0,
                "keyPattern": "{ f.t: 1.0, f.v: 1.0, ai: -1.0 }",
                "isMultiKey": 1,
                "boundsVerbose": "field #0['f.t']: [\"rel\", \"rel\"], field #1['f.v']: [true, true], field #2['ai']: [MaxKey, MinKey]",
                "yieldMovedCursor": 0,
                "dupsTested": 228327,
                "dupsDropped": 0,
                "seenInvalidated": 0,
                "matchTested": 0,
                "keysExamined": 228327,
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what can be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: When you try to run the individual elements of the $and-clause as separate queries, does the index get used for all of them?

Comment: Yes, it does @Philipp

Comment: Judging from the explain, it does use index to initially narrow down the search. Then it goes on and scans/filters the actual documents. If it were in, say, mysql, this query would be a 6-table join, with 5 tables being your facets table. You probably shouldn't expect this to perform as well as a simpler query.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongo inner workings well enough to say if this is "by design", an oversight or a bug.